# Disk writes in Mac OS Mojave (10.14.6)

Tags: macos, io

Good day everyone!

I am trying to dissect MacOS to remove functions I do not need such as Siri, Spotlight, Sidecar stuff, etc.

Mainly, I follow https://gist.github.com/pwnsdx and similar resources all over the Internet
(it's over 9000 of them).

I notice that kernel_task writes significant amount of data for no apparent reason on outside.

Doing `sudo fs_usage -w kernel_task` gets me to this:

```
07:49:30.567224    WrMeta[AP]      D=0x00070ee7  B=0x1000   /dev disk1  0.000105 W kernel_task.703966
07:49:30.567313    WrMeta[AP]      D=0x00070fca  B=0x1000   /dev/disk1  0.000105 W kernel_task.703966
07:49:30.567329    WrMeta[AP]      D=0x00071545  B=0x1000   /dev/disk1  0.000081 W kernel_task.703966
07:49:30.567334    WrMeta[AP]      D=0x0007198f  B=0x1000   /dev/disk1  0.000067 W kernel_task.703966
07:49:30.567399    WrMeta[AP]      D=0x0007245d  B=0x1000   /dev/disk1  0.000121 W kernel_task.703966
07:49:30.567416    WrMeta[AP]      D=0x0007258f  B=0x1000   /dev/disk1  0.000126 W kernel_task.703966
```

Roughly it happens every 4 seconds.

Investigating through say Console or `ps -ax` does not give me anything I can cling to.

What is outstanding - the kernel_task has a particular number of a task spawned, in this case it is `kernel_task.703966`, so "task" numbered `703966`.

I have done previous research over Internet including this site but nothing what can point to source. I tried to map supposedly destination `D=0x00070ee7` (example) to decimal hoping to get iNode of a file written but no luck. Everything I know is that *something* tries to write *some* metadata *somewhere* on filesystem.

Any ideas how to dig further?

Thanks for input.

Comment: `ps aux` will get an app name from its PID… but so will Activity Monitor. 70,000 is a pretty high number, so I'd expect your Mac has been up quite some time. You are aware that kernel_task is the actual root of all processes?

Comment: Yes, I am aware that kernel_task is like init in osx. 
```ps aux```  won't give me anything, the "task" number does not map to PID of a process here. Uptime is 8 days. Everything I run is: Thunderbird, Google Chrome, WhatsApp and Eclipse and I can see writes made by these processes in Activity Monitor.

I think kernel_task has some sort of API, scheduling mechanism where userprocess can query IO thru kernel. So I am trying to find out where query is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

I just did a fair amount of "digging" these past few days for a kernel_task issue that was writing terabytes of data to my HDD every few days. While that seems to have been a bug with Time Machine or with Mojave's implementation of APFS that I will document elsewhere, I would say that your usage of the **fs_usage** utility also gives you the ability to screen the processes that are reading that same type of metadata that you are observing is being written.

Try running this command sometime in another **Terminal** window to find clues that will help you understand what processes are interested in reading the metadata directly from the **/dev/disk1** device:

```
sudo fs_usage -w -f diskio | grep RdMeta | grep " /dev/disk1"
```

Note: I have a fusion drive so I had to replace `" /dev/disk1"` with `" /dev/disk2"`

One more thing: The interwebs do not seem to understand the meaning behind the bracketed notations that follow the "WrMeta" and "RdMeta" data values for the **CALL** field of the **fs_usage** command. There is an unanswered StackExchange question [asking about the meaning of the fs_usage CALL column](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/299175/what-does-that-mean-of-pginst3p-rdmetast3up-when-use-fs-usage-in-osx), with comments suggesting that this is information meaningful only to Apple developers. My supposition is that this square bracketed information indicates the method that was used to save the metadata in question, and is not an indication of the type of metadata that was being saved.